# Rational expression word problem.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, rational-functions

In one of my courses im learning rational expressions and we've done all of the basic operations for rational expressions im just having trouble with connecting the real life examples to rational expressions. For example this is one of the problems i cannot get past any help is appreciated.

Nikki and Kelly can create math problems for a particular course in 20 hours. Alone, Nikki can write out all of the problems 4 hours faster than Kelley could if she were to work alone. How long would it take each person to write the problems if they worked alone?

Comment: In such problems it's useful to take velocity (i.e. courses per hour) as unknowns. $n+k=1/20$, $1/n-1/k=-4$, however the resulting quadratic equation doesn't have square discriminant. [$n = \sqrt{101}/40 - 9/40, k = 11/40 - \sqrt{101}/40$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n%2Bk%3D1%2F20%2C+1%2Fn-1%2Fk%3D-4)